# eslint warning interpretation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eslint

I've been playing around a bit with ES6 and angular and I'm using `eslint-plugin-angular` to validate my javascript. I have the following service:

```
export function runBlock ($rootScope, $state, $log) {
  'ngInject';

  $rootScope.$on( '$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
    // ...
  } );
```

But `eslint` gives me the following error:

```
The "$on" call should be assigned to a variable, in order to be
destroyed during the $destroy event
```

I mean I understand the warning, but I've never done this in my previous angular projects, should I have done what the error suggests? Why is it needed/good practice?

The docs for `eslint-plugin-angular` reference [John Papa's angular styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide), but I didn't really find a mention of this situation there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not only does the johnpapa styleguide not mention this situation, it actually includes an example of ignoring the return of `$rootScope.$on`. However, the discussion on [one of the eslint-plugin-angular issues](https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular/issues/114) clarifies the intent a little bit:

> If a controller is registering a listener on `$rootScope` it should probably be manually destroyed in "`$destroy`" since root scope will outlive all the controllers. --[davidmason](https://github.com/davidmason)

That post also indirectly references the "Directives should clean up after themselves" best practice from [the AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

So bottom line: A regular `$scope` object will eventually be destroyed when its controller does, and take its event listeners with it (assuming you haven't done any kind of circular referencing that keeps it in scope). `$rootScope` never dies, and therefore never releases its event handlers. If your controller is adding an event listener to `$rootScope`, it should remove that handler in your controller's `$destroy` handler.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense!